# O que este trecho de código PHP faz? Minhas validações falham por causa dele

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que já peguei em andamento e estou tendo problemas na exibição de dados para certas validações. Preciso entender o que esta linha faz:

```
foreach ($queries as $id => $query) 
    if (!in_array($id, array('pagina', 'codigo', 'cidade', 'finalidade', 'tipo', 'imovel', 'bairro', 'dormitorios', 'valorMin', 'valorMax')) || empty($query)) 
        unset($queries[$id]);
```

Alguém consegue "traduzir"?

Comment: Você está fazendo muitas perguntas em um curto espaço de tempo, quanto a isso não há problema, porém suas perguntas estão ficando mal formatadas, por favor, perca um pouco mais de tempo redigindo suas perguntas, para que não tenhamos que corrigi-las. Abs.

Comment: Outra observação em relação às suas perguntas é que elas poderiam ser respondidas com uma simples consulta à documentação do PHP. Toda e qualquer função do PHP está muito bem documentada, então você não deveria ter problemas para compreender trechos de código mais simples :)

Answer (score 4):

Linha por linha:

```
foreach ($queries as $id => $query)
```

Loop sobre a array `$queries`. Para cada item, o valor da chave será guardado em `$id`, e o que está sob a chave será guardado em `$query`.

```
    if (!in_array($id, array('pagina', 'codigo', 'cidade', 'finalidade', 'tipo', 'imovel', 'bairro', 'dormitorios', 'valorMin', 'valorMax')) || empty($query))
```

Se a chave atual não for nenhuma das listadas, ou se o conteúdo de `$query` for vazio

```
        unset($queries[$id]);
```

Remove a chave `$id` da array `$queries`.